server receives accept-encoding header even if client doesn't send
I am sending a curl request to an echo server ( echo.free.beeceptor.com ) and even I don't include accept-encoding header in request, echo server shows it received the header.
% curl -v https://echo.free.beeceptor.com                       
*   Trying 147.182.252.2:443...
* Connected to echo.free.beeceptor.com (147.182.252.2) port 443
* ALPN: curl offers h2,http/1.1
....
< HTTP/2 200 
< access-control-allow-origin: *
< alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000
< content-type: application/json
< date: Tue, 02 Jul 2024 06:27:02 GMT
< server: Caddy
< vary: Accept-Encoding
< 
{
  "method": "GET",
  "protocol": "https",
  "host": "echo.free.beeceptor.com",
  "path": "/",
  "ip": "115.110.154.68:62921",
  "headers": {
    "Host": "echo.free.beeceptor.com",
    "User-Agent": "curl/8.4.0",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    **"Accept-Encoding": "gzip"**
  },
  "parsedQueryParams": {}

Does curl internally add this header? Which I don't think as same behaviour is seen on Postman. What logic can explain this?
Tried to look for Accept-encoding in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding but it also doesn't throw any light on this behaviour.

The Accept-Encoding header contains the capabilities of the used http client to decode compressed or otherwise encoded bodies. Why should the user manually define a capability of the client if the client itself knows way better what it can decode?

@Robert Its not about client capabilities. Even if curl has capability to accept encoded content it doesn't send the "Accept-encoding" header in request headers( as per verbose logs)  but echo server shows it does.

Why did you cut out the part our curls output that shows you what curl sent the server? But yes it's perfectly normal for HTTP clients to set headers by default.

You are simply using defect online service that shows wrong data.
Prove it yourself:

Start Wireshark and listen for tcp port 80 on your main network adapter
Execute curl -v http://echo.free.beeceptor.com
Check the curl output and the transmitted data in Wireshark both will show you the request

GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: echo.free.beeceptor.com
User-Agent: curl/8.7.1
Accept: */*

Or do the same using OpenSSL (as a telnet client with TLS capabilities) sending a manually crafted HTTP request:

Execute openssl s_client -host echo.free.beeceptor.com -port 443 (open TLS connection to the server)
Openssl connect to the server and then you can write data to it like in Telnet. Send the request

GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: echo.free.beeceptor.com
User-Agent: curl/8.7.1
Accept: */*

And then press return three times to end the HTTP request. You will see the HTTP response again contains  "Accept-Encoding": "gzip" which you have not sent to the server.

Thanks @Robert. Indeed echo.free.beeceptor.com is a buggy echo server.
